# show the column of the table in a color if the value in a cell is passed javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table for some calculations and if cell value is passed I want to show that column of the table in a color. 
I have this for the moment :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#myTable td.y_n').each(function(){
     if ($(this).text() < 0.4) {
         $(this).css('background-color','#a9edb8');
     }
     else {
       $(this).css('background-color','#eda9ca');
     }
   });
 });
</script>
```

but this is only for the cell.

Any idea? thanks!

Comment: i suggest you use `.addClass()` also try to convert the `$(this).text()` into `int or float`

Comment: Please check my answer once in answers, and try to not use else condition. For that you can write default CSS for color green for all td's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your goal correctly, you want to set the background color of an entire column if one if the `y_n` cells contains a numeric value and choose the color based on that value. 
To set the entire column, you could get the tablecells at the corresponding indices, but easier is to use a column group:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var cols =  $('#myTable col'); //get the column groups
  $('#myTable td.y_n').each(function(){
   var text = this.innerText; //text of the td
    if(text.length > 0 && !isNaN(this.innerText)){ //check if it's a number
     var ind = $(this).index(); //the index of the td inside its tr = the column index
      $(cols[ind]).css('background-color', parseFloat(text) < 0.4 ? '#a9edb8' : '#eda9ca'); //set the col of the column group
    }
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
<colgroup>
  <col>
  <col>
  <col>
</colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td>r1</td>
    <td class='y_n'></td>
    <td class='y_n'>.7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>r2</td>
    <td class='y_n'>.1</td>
    <td class='y_n'>.6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>r3</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myTable td.y_n').each(function(i,v) {
    if (parseFloat($(this).text()) < 0.4) {
      $(this).closest("table").find("td").eq(i).addClass("pass");
    } else {
      $(this).closest("table").find("td").eq(i).addClass("fail");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.pass {
  background-color: #a9edb8
}
.fail {
  background-color: #eda9ca
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">

  <tr>

    <td class='y_n'>
      .3
    </td>
    <td class='y_n'>
      .6
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='y_n'>
      .2
    </td>
    <td class='y_n'>
     .9
    </td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td class='y_n'>
      .9
    </td>
    <td class='y_n'>
     .1
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Use `parseFloat()` then compare

Comment: yes you can use `.parent()` another option is `.closest("tr")` to add the class to the tr where you wan to add the color

Comment: Are you sure that would solve the problem? OP asked to color the column, not the row.

Comment: lol.. it was a misunderstading. the first one will color the cell. i thought you want the color on row.

Comment: @Nda.S it will color only the td since you add the class to td itself.

Comment: @Nda.S change what?please clarify

Comment: @Nda.S check the update answer the first one. it will add the color to only the td of the table

Comment: can you add more information i dont get what you want edit the OP show what you want and show the html structure of what you are trying now

Answer (score 0):

I am not saying this is the best way because i have use so many loops, but you can achieve your requirement by this code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable tr').each(function(index,event) {
    $(event).children('td').each(function(indexI,eventI) {
      if ($(eventI).text() < 0.4) {
        $('#myTable tr').each(function(indexIn,eventIn) {
            $(eventIn).children('td').eq(indexI).css('background-   color','#eda9ca');
        });
      } 
    }); 
  });
});
```

Best of luck :)

Comment: created a plunker, if it matches your requirement.
https://plnkr.co/edit/4fOUFWMM8UB61tucqKC3?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve like this. in `each` `i` is index and `e` will be current element. And i just added `with="100"` to table so its looks proper.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myTable td.y_n').each(function(i,e) {
    if ($(e).text() < 0.4) {
      $(e).css('background-color','#a9edb8');
    } else {
      $(e).css('background-color','#eda9ca');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" width="100">
  <tr>
    <td class='y_n'>
      .3
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='y_n'>
      .6
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are many rows (a lot of them) in your table, you might be better of using [colgroups with col structure](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_col.asp) in your table, and put the background on the col-element. Anyway, you can always do this:

```js
$(function() {
 $('table a').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
    var index = $(this).html();
    colHighlight($(this).closest('table'), index);
  });
});

function colHighlight(table, colIndex) {
 var bodyCells = table.find('tbody td');
 bodyCells.css('background-color', 'transparent');
    bodyCells.filter(':nth-child(' + colIndex + ')').css({
   'background-color': 'yellow'
  });
}
```

```css
table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Head 1</th>
      <th>Head 2</th>
      <th>Head 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">
        Highlight column:
        <a href="#">1</a>
        <a href="#">2</a>
        <a href="#">3</a>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```